# IBM V3700 adding new disk physically

Tags: storage-area-network, ibm

I dont hold much experience in SAN storage, therefore had to ask experts here :)

I have IBM v3700 San Storage with 2 enclosures hosting 36 2.5 SAS disks (2.5 inches, 15k rpm 300gb x 36) splitted into different raid level which are connected to different servers.

Now we want to add another server which requires large capacity for SAP application. If i add 1 TB x 6 drives (2.5 inches SAS 10krpm), and make separate RAID 10 for new server. will it be Ok ? I mean adding different size disk and assign it to new server is supported?

Comment: *I mean adding different size disk and assign it to new server is supported?*  I don't have experience with this IBM product specifically, but I'd think that *should* be OK.  Do you have the product documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added 900gbx6 (10krpm) Drives in v3700 SAN, and created Raid5 with spare and assigned this new mdisk pool to the new server. All went fine. 
Our IT manager was so concerned about possibility that adding new drives of different size may harm the existence system, that's why I had to post this silly query